# Android unit testing - how to run tests in same project as application?

Tags: android, unit-testing

In the Android LunarLander sample project, the unit tests are included right in the project, in a (non-source) folder called 'tests'. This is in line with the SDK testing guide which recommends this layout as opposed to creating tests in a separate project. However, I have no idea how I can actually run these tests.

I can't create an Android Junit Test run configuration:

- if I try to 'run all test in project or package' it complains that manifest file doesn't contain instrumentation info - clearly it's using the top-level manifest file instead of the tests manifest file.
- if I try to 'run a single test', I can't find any because tests isn't a source folder, and if I set it as a source folder, errors pop up, since it assumes the test class should be in a package starting with 'tests.src'.

It's starting to seem to me that this sample is broken... I hope I am wrong, since I'd rather embed tests into my project and be able to run them easily (instead of creating a separate test project that links to project for application under test). Does anybody know how I can run these tests? Thanks...

Comment: You are talking about using Eclipse, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recommend a single all-in-one directory because it makes your files easy maintainable in many situation, for instance when dealing with source control.

It doesn't matter where the test project is located int the file system, however, you must import it into your Eclipse's workspace, same as what you did for the LunarLander project:

[image]

If everything goes well, your Package Explorer should look something like this:

[image]

In my Android 4.2 samples, things are not going well, it seems that the source code of LunarLander test project is not up-to-date:

1. it doesn't come with project.properties file.
2. it uses same package name as LunarLander project, resulting Eclipse to be fooled when importing package/class from the referenced LunarLander project.
3. it doesn't automatically add the LunarLander project to test project's classpath, resulting imported package/class from the referenced LunarLander project is invisible.

Once you resolve all issues, you should able to run/debug Android JUnit Test from test project.

Comment: I know that I can create a second project for my tests, and I got this going easily. But that's not what I want to do; my question was in regards to having tests in the same project, which is how I (and most people?) structure vanilla Java projects. Notice in your pic that the LunarLander project has a 'tests' folder containing the same files as the other tests project you have. How do you run the tests in 'tests' in LunarLander?

Comment: What google means ([see here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#TestProjects)) regards to "having tests in same project" is purely in file system level, i.e. how should you organize your project's folders/files on your hard disk. When comes into Eclipse, the test project must be logically imported and formed as a separate project in Eclipse's Package Explorer. The subfolder tests has its own project description structure and only shown as a normal folder with raw files when importing the LunarLander project. This is how ADT is designed and supposed to work.

Comment: When playing with the samples, What I do usually is using `File -> Import... -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace` import the project (better to work on a copy of samples as this will change the original file under sdk/samples folder). Note that this will analyse and detect all sub-projects (if they are well formed) and import both into Eclipse all in one go. However, they are still shown as two projects in the Package Explorer. Remember that the Package Explorer is only a logical view to you project on the file system. You have to run/debug your tests from the test project.